# JFrame either won't show up or it's just one line or cannot be closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm writing a game and when I collide with a computer and press E it should open a little `JFrame` with a question. But sometimes the frame opens but it cannot be seen or closed when right click on it. Or when it shows it just one little line and nothing more like this: http://postimg.org/image/7upz61cjl.

There's source code:

```
public class Computer() extends AbstractActor {

     public Computer() throws IOException {
            super("computer", 0, 0, 80, 48, 100, "resources/sprites/computer.png"); 
            question = new JLabel();
            input = new JTextField();
            confirm = new Button("Confirm");

        getQuestion(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("resources/questions.txt"))));

        confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (input.getText().equals(password) && net != null) {
                    getWorld().removeActor(net);
                }
                window.dispose();
                window = null;
            }
        });

    }

    public void use(Ripley ripley) {
        if (window == null && !(input.getText().equals(password))) {
            window = new JFrame("Answer this to shut lasers.");
            window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(window.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            window.add(question);
            window.add(input);
            window.add(confirm);

            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    window = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void act() {
        if (net == null) {
            net = (LaserNet)getActorByName("laser net");
        }
    }

    public void getQuestion(InputStreamReader file) throws IOException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = -1;
        while (num % 2 != 0)
            num = rand.nextInt(10);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file)) {
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i == num) {
                    question.setText(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                    password = line;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: can u add more details.what do you mean by `when it shows it just one little line and nothing more`

Comment: The construction of the your frame (`window`), looks like it could easily be a `JOptionPane`. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: BTW - `new FileInputStream("resources/questions.txt")`  That will not work once the app. is in a Jar.  Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Dont't set the window to null, do window.dispose()

Comment: (I think `window` is set to `null` because the `use` method checks whether `window` is `null`.) The screenshot you added shows a main window titled "Unknown territory" with a rectangular graphic (the world?) in the center. Is the rectangular graphic in a separate window? Otherwise I am surprised the question/answer frame can be both behind the graphic and in front of the main window. Can you add the code that creates the main window and the graphic?

Comment: I figured it out. It was line  window.setResizable(false); that was cousing it.